# R compute mean and sum of value in dataframe using group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where I want :
By groups in two columns, I want to compute mean and know the number of element that have this value :

```
test=data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,4,5,8,5,5,7),
                b=c('A','A','B','A','B','B','A','B','B','A'),
                c=runif(10, -5,0))
```

I want for rows that have same 'a' and 'b' compute the mean of 'c' and know the sum of 'a' used to compute the mean

I tried this to compute mean :

```
test_mean=test %>%
  group_by(a,b) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars("c"), mean) 
# %>% mutate(d = sum(a))


a   b      c      
1   A   -3.138246
1   B   -0.411621
2   A   -2.787820
4   B   -2.343191
5   B   -3.323057
7   A   -4.765974
8   A   -4.596118
```

But I want also a fourth column with the sum :

```
a   b      c          d    
1   A   -3.138246     2
1   B   -0.411621     1
2   A   -2.787820     1
4   B   -2.343191     1
5   B   -3.323057     3
7   A   -4.765974     1
8   A   -4.596118     1
```

Comment: just do `...summarise_at(vars("c"), funs(mean, n()))`

Comment: Great thank exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `summarize_at`, plain `summarize` will do in this case:

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,4,5,8,5,5,7),
                b=c('A','A','B','A','B','B','A','B','B','A'),
                c=runif(10, -5,0))
test %>% 
    group_by(a,b) %>% 
    summarize(c = mean(c), d = n())
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'a' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#> # Groups:   a [6]
#>       a b          c     d
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1 A     -2.83      2
#> 2     1 B     -0.992     1
#> 3     2 A     -2.92      1
#> 4     4 B     -4.83      1
#> 5     5 B     -3.19      3
#> 6     7 A     -0.639     1
#> 7     8 A     -2.25      1
```

If you have multiple variables, then consider using `across` (dplyr >= 1.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, .(c = mean(c), d = .N), .(a, b)]
```